# Merge google-vision and google-mobile-vision into google-mlkit

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I recently became aware of the [google-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-vision) (704 questions, seven this month) and [google-mobile-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mobile-vision) (four questions) tags, both of which I believe should become a synonym for [google-mlkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mlkit) (318 questions, 16 this month).

google-vision, which mentions Google Mobile Vision API in its description, is about on-device machine learning (ML) for iOS and Android apps and which Google [has moved](https://developers.google.com/vision) to be part of [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit). google-cloud-vision is Google's [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision) that uses pre-trained ML models via [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) APIs.

Making google-vision and google-mobile-vision synonyms of google-mlkit will eliminate confusion between tagging for on-device ML (google-mlkit) and Cloud Vision API (google-cloud-vision).